# how to insert multiple values from multiple textarea into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am having an issue while inserting from a textarea into mysql.i have a form which contains multiple textarea.`form.php`

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php">
<thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Center Name</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>IP Details</th>
                </tr>   
<tr>
                     <td valign="top">1</td>
                     <td valign="top">ABCE</td>
                     <td valign="top">abce</td>
                     <td valign="top">abce123</td>
                     <td valign="top">
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="ip_details[]">59.162.181.45,27.251.106.75,59.162.182.155</textarea><br/>
                        </td> 
</tr>   
<tr  class="alt-row">
                     <td valign="top">2</td>
                     <td valign="top">XYZ</td>
                     <td valign="top">xyz</td>
                     <td valign="top">1234</td>
                     <td valign="top">
                        <textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="ip_details[]">54.23.87.32,198.12.65.64,34.56.43.12</textarea><br/>
                         </td>
                    </tr>

<tr>
                    <td colspan="5" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" /></td>
                </tr>
</form>
```

i want to insert these array values into a database which will enter the ip_details[0] to ABCE row and ip_details[1] to XYZ row in database.
when i do

```
$a=$_POST['ip_details'];

$b= $_POST['ip_details'][0];
echo "$b";

$c= $_POST['ip_details'][1];
echo "$c";
```

it show me values of ip_details from ABCE and XYZ.

i want to add these array values of ip in the ipdetails column in database.id_center(primary key)my table structure.show create table `table_name`

```
CREATE TABLE `center_listt` (
id_center int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
center_name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
user_name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
password varchar(10) NOT NULL,
ipdetails varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_center`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


id_center  center_name  user_name  password  ipdetails
  1         ABCE         abce       1234      59.162.181.45,27.251.106.75,59.162.182.155
  2         XYZ          xyz        1234      54.23.87.32,198.12.65.64,34.56.43.12
```

i cant find a way to do that.all i mange to do is echo the array in my browser.need help in inserting in the db like the same

Comment: Not related to your answer but go you further first read [**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and avoid storing comma separated values in database

Comment: these ip with comma separated will be checked for each center and allow access to that ip only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$ip_details = $_POST['ip_details'];
$values = array(
    array('ipdetails' => '"'.$ip_details[0].'"'),
    array('ipdetails' => '"'.$ip_details[1].'"'),
);

$columns = implode(', ', array_keys($values[0]));
foreach($values as $value) {
    $value = implode(',', $value);
    $statement = "INSERT INTO `center_listt` (ipdetails) VALUES ($value) ";
    //echo $statement . "<br/>";
   $res=mysql_query($statement);
    if(!$res) {
        die('could not connect'.mysql_error());
    }
echo "gg";
}
}


?>
```

column count dosent match value count at row 1 because its expecting all the array key to be inserted in the columnlist in mysql insert statement.

it will run but the output you are expecting as shown in database where already a table is there with field values just you want to input these ip's to there in a ipdetails column where it will match with id_center.

it will only insert a new row not that you are expecting to happen

Comment: try my modified code it will add ip in different row but not what you want

Comment: it works as u have said but inserting in different rows.so in near future to add again an array of ip from textarea will add in different rows with repeatation of data instead of updating the single row for different center_name respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Center Name</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>IP Details</th>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">1</td>
            <td valign="top">ABCE</td>
            <td valign="top">abce</td>
            <td valign="top">abce123</td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="abc" />
                <textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="ip_details[]">59.162.181.45,27.251.106.75,59.162.182.155</textarea><br/>
            </td> 
        </tr>   
        <tr  class="alt-row">
            <td valign="top">2</td>
            <td valign="top">XYZ</td>
            <td valign="top">xyz</td>
            <td valign="top">1234</td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="XYZ" />
                <textarea rows="4" cols="40"  name="ip_details[]">54.23.87.32,198.12.65.64,34.56.43.12</textarea><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>`enter code here`

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" /></td>
        </tr>
</form>


    <?php

if($_POST){

    $count = count($_POST['row']);

    for($i = 0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE SET field = '{$_POST['row'][$i]}',ip = '{$_POST['ip_details'][$i]}' ";
        echo "<br>".$sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: its inserting ip in different rows every time i submit.i want to inset the ip's to the exact same row everytime.like ip's in the 1st textarea will get inserted in the table with id_center=1 and next textarea ip's will be inserted in table with id_Center=2.thank you